Python to Excel, with multiple elements
new to coding.
I have a question concerning lists within Python and putting said list into an excel file. My list is similar to as follows.
List1 =
[[[a,1], [b,2], [c,3], [d,4], [e,5]],
[[aa,11], [bb,22], [cc,33], [dd,44],[ee,55]],
[[aaa,111], [bbb,222], [ccc,333], [ddd,444],[eee,555]],
[[aaaa,1111], [bbbb,2222], [cccc,3333], [dddd,4444],[eeee,5555]],

Lets say my list is a lot bigger than that but same amount of elements in each list as seen above. Now my goal is for it to save to excel something like this:(https://i.sstatic.net/MBnNhHHp.png)
not really interested in the direction if it loads down or to the sides, I would like to see the list in excel is all. Thank you for any help
I dont even know where to start

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

The csv module provides a simple way to make a text file with lines of comma-separated column values that Excel will load:
import csv

list1 = [[['a',1], ['b',2], ['c',3], ['d',4], ['e',5]],
         [['aa',11], ['bb',22], ['cc',33], ['dd',44],['ee',55]],
         [['aaa',111], ['bbb',222], ['ccc',333], ['ddd',444],['eee',555]],
         [['aaaa',1111], ['bbbb',2222], ['cccc',3333], ['dddd',4444],['eeee',5555]]]

# open with newline='' (csv.writer requirement)
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fout:
    # wrap open file in a CSV writer.
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    # Add headers.  Each row is a list of column values
    writer.writerow(['column1', 'column2'])
    # Iterate the list of list of lists:
    for lis in list1:
        # writerows takes a list of lists, and treated as rows of columns
        writer.writerows(lis)
        # write a blank row between lists
        writer.writerow([])

Output (text):
column1,column2
a,1
b,2
c,3
d,4
e,5

aa,11
bb,22
cc,33
dd,44
ee,55

aaa,111
bbb,222
ccc,333
ddd,444
eee,555

aaaa,1111
bbbb,2222
cccc,3333
dddd,4444
eeee,5555

Output (Excel):


My apologies this is what I asked for, forgot to mention that I'm using pandas and excel, and is it possible for you to make the list go across instead down. instead the columns are rows. so 'a' would start at A2 and 'b' would go at B2. '1' would go in A3 and '2' would go in B3. I can ask another question in general but if you could id appreciate it
